# Postgresql queries in NPOCO

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql, npoco

I am quite new to the NPOCO + PostgreSQL Space as i have decided to stay off SQL Server for some time.

My issue is that usually write queries like this in NPOCO

```
   database.Execute("select userId from Users");
```

And everything works fine in the SQL Server world.  Coming to the PostGreSQL World, I am bumped by the queries looking a bit strange like this

```
  SELECT "UserId", from dbo."Users"
```

Now I am curious to know how one would use PostgreSQL Queries in NPOCO seeing that the column and table names have to be in quotes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The column and table names in postgres only have to be in quotes if they include upper-case or special characters. That is, by default, the postgres SQL parser will force lower-case for all unquoted names. That makes things a bit more convenient for interactive use, but much less convenient if you have software auto-generating table and column names with upper-case letters, spaces, or emoji.

In other words, if the table name is `users` and the column name is `userid`, then the query `select userid from users` would work just fine. It's only when the table name is `Users` that you have to start quoting.

The other sql difference I notice is specifying the `dbo` schema. Postgres supports schemas (also known as "namespaces"), and has a search path available for them. It also has a default "public" schema. The default `search_path` is:

```
"$user", public
```

Which just means that if you `select * from foo` as username `bob`, postgres will check for `bob.foo` and then `public.foo` and use whatever it finds first as `foo`. You can alter the `search_path` if you'd like:

```
SET search_path to dbo,public;
```

And that will allow you to skip the "`dbo.`" part of your queries.

Comment: Not consistent with my experience, I lowercased everything and postgres says relation "IdentityUser" cannot be found

Comment: If you lowercased everything, then postgres wouldn't be looking for something with mixed case like "IdentityUser". Is it possible that your ORM is using mixed case automatically?